# How do I access an element in a nested schema?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, postman

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b8d1ecbb745685c31ad8603"),  
        "name" : "abc",  
        "email" : "abc@gmail.com",  
        "projectDetails" : [   
        {  
            "technologies" : [  
                "abc",   
                "abc"  
            ],  
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b8d1ecbb745685c31ad8604"),  
            "projectName" : "abc",  
            "projectDescription" : "abc",  
            "manager" : "abc",  
            "mentor" : "abc"  
        }  
    ],  
    "__v" : 0  
}
```

Here, projectDetails is an array of objects. I want to update the element "projectName" in projectDetails. How do I write a PUT request for the same in Postman?

Comment: Do you want to update projectName of a specific project?

Comment: Are you talking about just postman URL or both URL and mongoose query for the same?

Comment: @PiyushBansal, yes I want to update projectName of a specific project.

Comment: @PavanVora, I would like to know both URL and mongoose query for the same.

Comment: is it required to send userId from postman or you have implemented  JWT to get the userId from token?

Comment: @PavanVora, actually I have been working on the back-end of this project, and I am completely new to this. I am using Postman only for testing.

Answer (score 0):

> Try below query

```
db.users.update({ "email" : "abc@gmail.com","projectDetails._id":ObjectId("5b8d1ecbb745685c31ad8604")},{ $set: { "projectDetails.$.projectName" : "test" } })
```

> Your url should be like this

```
http://localhost:3000/project/5b8d1ecbb745685c31ad8604
```

> Your put request as mentioned below

```
router.route("/updateProject",function(req,res){
var id = req.query.project_id; // Check syntax for framework you are using
```

});

Comment: Update query as per your requirement